# AngularJS add ng-model at compile time

Tags: angularjs

I have previously created a directive called click-to-edit

you would use it like

```
<click-to-edit="someValue">
```

where `$scope.someValue=7;`

I have since realized that i need to use the ngModel controller, and it would be EASIER if i could recompile this directive and add `ng-model="someValue"` to the template. Im having trouble doing this as it is giving me the error

`"Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'clickToEdit', can't be found!"`

This is obviously because i have

`require:'ngModel'`

this is a snippet of the code so far

```
return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: true,
      require: 'ngModel',
      priority: 100,

      compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
          // Correct ngModel for isolate scope
              tAttrs.$set('ngModel', tAttrs.clickToEdit, false);
          }
          return {
              post: linkFn

          };
      },
      scope: {
          dp: '=?',
          type: '@',
          fn: '=?', //<--- formula
          editFn:'&?' // if you want to execute a function on a valid save, add this
      }
```

What i simply want to do, is take a directive that looks like

`<click-to-edit="model"/>`
and change it to

`<click-to-edit="model" ng-model="model"/>`

and then have it compile and work as expected.

Let me know if you need other code.

Comment: Looks like what and change it to what?

Comment: @HenrikN it was formatting issues. Should be readable now

Comment: here is a plunk

http://plnkr.co/edit/8YEGwYkEogbKLKodztGz?p=preview

Comment: Why can't you just use: <click-to-edit ng-model="model"/> ?? (Which is the natural way to use directives that require an ngModel)

Comment: cause we have a ton of templates that would need to be retrofitted. But if this is not possible then that is the last choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you've considered this - but why not just do:

```
 <click-to-edit ng-model="model"/>
```

To answer the original question,  I suggest adding a body directive:

```
.directive('body', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    compile: function(element, attr) {
        $('[click-to-edit]', element).attr('ng-model', 'model');
    }
  }
})
```

[Plunker Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bbLr96DmIhA0B7iHVSDD?p=info)

Comment: yes i realize that we could do this, but it would require a lot of templates to be updated

Comment: still getting
"Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'clickToEdit', can't be found!"

Comment: Shouldn't be, the model should be added

Comment: did you try it with this plnkr?

plnkr.co/edit/8YEGwYkEogbKLKodztGz?p=preview

Comment: Updated answer. Changed attribute name looked up using jquery. Should work now.